# Why isn't \\b in gsubfn in R working for me?

Tags: r, regex, gsubfn

I have a string like this:

```
vect <- c("Thin lines are not great, I am in !!! AND You shouldn't be late OR you loose")
```

I want to replace, "in" to %in%", "AND" to "&", "OR" to "|".

I know this can be done using gsub like below:

```
gsub("\\bin\\b","%in%", vect),
```

but I need three different lines for each of the replacement, hence I choose to use `gsubfn`.

so I tried,

```
gsubfn("\\bin\\b|\\bAND\\b|\\bOR\\b", list("in"="%in%", "AND"= "&", "OR"="|"), vect)
```

but It returns a string with nothing changed, for some reason `\\b` is not working for the string. However, `\\b` does work great with `gsub` and I am able to replace all the three strings in by piping together using `gsub`.

My question is, why `\\b` is not working inside `gsubfn`. what I am missing inside my regex?

Please help.

**Output** should be:

```
"Thin lines are not great, I am %in% !!! & You shouldn't be late | you loose"
```

This works:

```
gsubfn("\\w+", list("in"="%in%", "AND"= "&", "OR"="|"), vect)
```

Comment: Ah yes, I remember going through the same head-scratching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Tcl regex engine is used, see [`gsubfn` docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/gsubfn.pdf):

> **If the R installation has tcltk capability then the
>   tcl engine is used** unless FUN is a proto object or `perl=TRUE` in which case the "R" engine is used (regardless of the setting of this argument).

So, word boundaries are defined with `\y`:

```
> gsubfn("\\y(in|AND|OR)\\y", list("in"="%in%", "AND"= "&", "OR"="|"), vect)
[1] "Thin lines are not great, I am %in% !!! & You shouldn't be late | you loose"
```

Ainother way is by using `\m` as leading word boundary and `\M` for a trailing word boundary:

```
> gsubfn("\\m(in|AND|OR)\\M", list("in"="%in%", "AND"= "&", "OR"="|"), vect)
[1] "Thin lines are not great, I am %in% !!! & You shouldn't be late | you loose"
```

You may pass `perl=TRUE` and use `\b`:

```
> gsubfn("\\b(in|AND|OR)\\b", list("in"="%in%", "AND"= "&", "OR"="|"), vect, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Thin lines are not great, I am %in% !!! & You shouldn't be late | you loose"
```

Comment: Any idea why `gsub` works without perl=T condition? Thanks for the help, Your answers are always great

Comment: @PKumar `gsub` uses TRE regex egnine, not Tcl, by default, and the version of TRE for R contains an implementation of both `\b` (just word boundary) and a pair of `\<` (leading word boundary) and `\>` (trailing word boundary).

Answer (score 4):

Add `perl = T` that should do it.

```
gsubfn("\\bin\\b|\\bAND\\b|\\bOR\\b", list("in"="%in%", "AND"= "&", "OR"="|"), vect, perl =T)
```

Output

```
[1] "Thin lines are not great, I am %in% !!! & You shouldn't be late | you loose"
```

---

From gsub documentation

> The POSIX 1003.2 mode of gsub and gregexpr does not work correctly with repeated word-boundaries (e.g., pattern = "\b"). Use perl = TRUE for such matches (but that may not work as expected with non-ASCII inputs, as the meaning of ‘word’ is system-dependent).

And gsubfn documentation

> ...   Other gsub arguments.

Doesn't explain why gsub works fine without the `perl` argument, but to do gsubfn it needs the `perl=T`

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately I can't accept more than one answer, Thanks for the help

Comment: Just note that you do not have to use PCRE regex (`perl=TRUE`) engine since Tcl regex engine also supports word boundaries.